# What potential litigation could a corporation face if you made your personal phone number public on social media?

Tags: united-states, employment, civil-law

I saw on someone's Facebook page that they were hired at a major corporation who told them that they needed to delete their phone number, and ask that every one of their friends delete the phone number from their end as well.
When I asked this person why this was a requirement, they said that it had to do with the possibility of a lawsuit.
Can someone familiar in this area explain more? Thanks!

Comment: Are they asking the person to delete their personal phone number or their work phone number?

Comment: I'm assuming it's a personal phone number. They didn't say, but that's probably what they implied.